# How do I replace all NA with mean in R?

Tags: r, missing-data

I have over 1500 columns in my dataset and 100+ of them contains at least one NA. I know I can replace NAs in a single column by

```
d$var[is.na(d$var)] <- mean(d$var, na.rm=TRUE)
```

but how do I do this too ALL the NAs in my dataset?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `na.aggregate` from `zoo`.  Loop through the columns of dataset (assuming all the columns are `numeric` ), apply the `na.aggregate` to replace the NA with `mean` values (by default) and assign it back to the dataset.

```
library(zoo)
df[] <- lapply(df, na.aggregate)
```

By default, the `FUN` argument of `na.aggregate` is `mean`:

> Default S3 method:
>
> na.aggregate(object, by = 1, ..., FUN = mean,
>                 na.rm = FALSE, maxgap = Inf)

To do this nondestructively:

```
df2 <- df
df2[] <- lapply(df2, na.aggregate)
```

or in one line:

```
df2 <- replace(df, TRUE, lapply(df, na.aggregate))
```

If there are non-numeric columns, do this only for the numeric columns by creating a logical index first

```
ok <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
df[ok] <- lapply(df[ok], na.aggregate)
```